# Extract values from url using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, url, substring

I have an input field that contains an URL. If the onchange event fires, there should be a jquery function that extract some values and pass it to another function. The problem is only to extract valus.

Here is the url

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Beach&aq=&sll=37.09024,-95.712891&sspn=47.972233,107.138672&vpsrc=6&ie=UTF8&hq=Beach+Hotel,&hnear=South+Wales&t=m&fll=-28.639489,153.610239&fspn=0.026139,0.052314&st=115703629269948245352&rq=1&ev=zi&split=1&ll=-28.5725225,124.52239&spn=0.026139,0.052314&z=15&iwloc=A&cid=4038837565330903688
```

I want to exctract the values from parameter *latitude* and *longitude*, which are located at `&ll=-28.5725225,124.52239`.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for jQuery for this.

```
var loc = "https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Beach&aq=&sll=37.09024,-95.712891&sspn=47.972233,107.138672&vpsrc=6&ie=UTF8&hq=Beach+Hotel,&hnear=South+Wales&t=m&fll=-28.639489,153.610239&fspn=0.026139,0.052314&st=115703629269948245352&rq=1&ev=zi&split=1&ll=-28.5725225,124.52239&spn=0.026139,0.052314&z=15&iwloc=A&cid=4038837565330903688 ";

loc = loc.split("&ll=")[1];
loc = loc.split("&")[0];
console.log(loc);
```